# Alexa Audio Player Directive

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to build an Alexa skill that can play an audio file. I'm trying to send an Audio Player Play directive in the Launch Request, but when I use this code, I get no response back from my Alexa. Does it look correct?

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log('IN LAUNCHREQUEST');
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .addDirective({
            type: 'AudioPlayer.Play',
            playBehavior: 'REPLACE_ALL',
            audioItem: {
                stream: {
                    token: "0",
                    url: "myurlhere",
                    offsetInMilliseconds: 0
                }
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You must return a "built" response, in the handler. So in you case the code would be:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log('IN LAUNCHREQUEST');
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .addDirective({
            type: 'AudioPlayer.Play',
            playBehavior: 'REPLACE_ALL',
            audioItem: {
                stream: {
                    token: "0",
                    url: "myurlhere",
                    offsetInMilliseconds: 0
                }
            }
        })
        .getResponse();
        // ^^^ add this line
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using alexa sdk v2 (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) then you can use inbuilt methods to play audio. Following methods are available to play long form audio.

```
addAudioPlayerPlayDirective(playBehavior: interfaces.audioplayer.PlayBehavior, url: string, token: string, offsetInMilliseconds: number, expectedPreviousToken?: string, audioItemMetadata? : AudioItemMetadata): this;
addAudioPlayerStopDirective(): this;
addAudioPlayerClearQueueDirective(clearBehavior: interfaces.audioplayer.ClearBehavior): this;
```

More information can be found on https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Building-Response.html

Following is a code snippet that I use in my lambda to play audio.

```
//Create Image to be displayed with song

const metadata = {
    title: 'Stopwatch Audio',
    art: {
        sources: [{
            url: imageUrl
        }]
    }
};
handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speechText).addAudioPlayerPlayDirective("REPLACE_ALL", audiofile, audiofile, 0, null, metadata).withShouldEndSession(true).getResponse();
```